# _SecItemAdd referenced from - Apple Keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, security

I am getting this error when trying to use Apple keychain.

1. I have `Security.framework` and `SystemConfiguration.framework` both
   linked.
2. The project run fines on my machine.
3. I send it to a friend, it throws 17 `_SecItemAdd` ,
   `_SecItemCopyMatching` , _Sec... , on his machine.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the necessary libraries. Make sure your friend is building the same scheme and/or target. Also check if you have added the framework properly in the target's Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries